# Structuring Data in Python (list from lists?)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm currently developing a script in Python 2.7 which pulls approximately 50 string values from a URL and places these values in a list.

For each of these 50 values, they each have a further respective 20 associated string values.

So for example, I may capture two initial values from a URL which are "Ford" and "BMW". I will then requery "Ford" to find associated models such as "Focus" and "Mondeo" etc....

Eventually I need to join those values to carry out a further URL query (ie. www.ford.com/fiesta and www.ford.com/mondeo and www.bmw.com/xxxx)

I am wondering what the best was is to structure my data? I am thinking of creating a list of parent values and then for each parent value, create a sub-list titles the parent value with its associated values in the list.

Is there a better way to structure the data?

Comment: Why not use custom classes?

Comment: I've got no experience of using custom classes :-(. Will have a Google now

Comment: Just follow the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/); it's an OO language, so you may as well learn how to define a class. It's simple enough.

Comment: Ah sorry Martijn. I understand how classes work in Python. I'm just wondering how the above would be structured in a class?!? Would there still be multiple lists in the class?

Comment: no, each entry could be an instance of the custom class. It depends on how complex your data is going to get. If all you want is urls with a list of names, the answer below is more than fine.

Answer (score 2):

A friendly advice: keep things simple.
Refer to the Zen of Python when in doubt: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/

"Simple is better than complex."

I would go for a dict of lists, or even better, a `defaultdict` (http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict


cars = defaultdict(list)

cars["Ford"].append("Mondeo")
cars["Ford"].append("Focus")
cars["BMW"].append("SuperCoolModel")

print cars
```

Gives:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'BMW': ['SuperCoolModel'], 'Ford': ['Mondeo', 'Focus']})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think an OOP approach is a good way to organize this kind of data, in order to have a high cohesion and make it easier to add new functionality. For example:

```
class CarBrand(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.domain = "http://www.%s.com/" % name.lower()

class CarModel(object):
    def __init__(self, name, brand):
        self.name = name
        self.brand = brand
    def url_query(self):
        return "%s%s" % (self.brand.domain, self.name.lower())
```